# How to destroy a Global Religion?

Tags: magic, religion, medieval

Assuming this is situated in a medieval-esque world with swords and magic.
The magic well consumes magic power, which is naturally absorbed into living beings so they have regeneration. The amount of magic power poured into a 'spell' would correspond to how strong it is, a fireball created with 100 mana would be ten times stronger then a fireball created with 10 mana. The 'spell' acts as a medium to convert magic power to say creation of flames, a higher class spell like pyroblast would convert this better. There are for example spells that allow strengthening of the body and cancellation of noise and melting into the shadows. There is no mind magic so controlling people with magic is not possible.

All of the people believe in the church and their teachings. Now for some reason, I would like to destroy this church as their leaders are corrupted and how they teach that humans are supreme over the other races etc etc.

It is preferable that this does not end in bloodshed. Killing would only make the problem worse. The goddess can't do anything to help.

**Now, how would one destroy the Church's influence and their followers faith in a year or less?** How would I go around convincing a kingdom of a million humans that the Church is wrong?

I have read about this situation in some books but the only few solutions that ever came up was warring between the hero and church factions.

I don't know what tags to put btw

Comment: Can they rather than destroying church's influence, change it from the inside ? Start a sub-church faith which acknowledges demons were also creations of goddess, and gain more followers, or convert the original church ?

Comment: Sky you're not really asking a worldbuilding question. Instead, it seems like you want us to write a good chunk of the story for you, which is kind of a no-no. VTC-ing as "too story based".

Comment: What are the teachings of the church ? Is their belief similar to "Christianity", as death due to bubonic plague weakened the believers as church actively says "God loves all of you.".

Comment: Well that might be ridiculously hard, I forgot to add a time limit too zzzz. Considering how the Church could just say that it is blasphemous and from some real life examples of religious opposition resulting in house arrests and a lot of other stuff.

Comment: @AndreiROM I don't mean to right a story, just a method to do this?

Comment: Destroying the Church's influence, sure. But destroying a billion's people's faith you cannot do (in a short time), it is too ingrained in the culture. Have a happy Thor's Day.

Comment: @sky - you're asking us to describe what a character might do in order to accomplish a goal, which fits the "Story based" close reason. Here's the thing: we can't possibly answer your post. Not well, anyway. The reason is that your heroes might expose the lies of the church through some sort of magic, by exposing the leader as a liar, by gaining human allies against them, etc. It all depends on the human interactions in your universe, there's no one clearly defined way in which they might win. There's no clear steps that have worked throughout history. On the contrary, it seems hopeless.

Comment: @AndreiROM kill me, im gonna change it around a bit

Comment: @sky - **I won't kill ya, I'll just settle for taking one of your eyes, *and* the use of your legs. MUAHAHAHAHA!!!** (to be clear, I'm just being silly. I'm not trying to pick on you by voting to close, friend, I just really don't think your question fits the WB SE scope. Check [this](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/risk-factor-definition-too-story-based) out for more details!)

Comment: Changing the opinion of nearly a billion people and upending the socio-political structure of their civilization, without bloodshed or mind-control magic, in a year or less? It can't be done. Perhaps if you eliminate one or two of these requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for a religion with >1 billion followers to die out?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/is-it-possible-for-a-religion-with-1-billion-followers-to-die-out)

Comment: @AndreiROM Is this slightly better? I don't know :P I just want to know how to destroy a religion XD

Comment: @James how is it a duplicate? It seems like the OP wants a way to actively kill off a religion instead of a whether a religion could dissappear passively?

Comment: [Small Gods by Terry Pratchett](https://www.amazon.com/Small-Gods-Discworld-Terry-Pratchett/dp/0062237373/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1470923205&sr=8-1&keywords=pratchett+small+gods): ask the god/goddess to raise a prophet outside the Church

Comment: @Planarian Because the answer is you can't kill off a religion at least not any religion that would be worth the effort.  Violence doesn't get rid of religion.

Comment: @James Violence can indeed get rid of religion. Here's the trivial case: kill all humans --> no human religions. Assuming the only sentient species is humans, of course.

Comment: @Frostfyre ...yeah sure that would work.

Comment: Have you looked at Martin Luther? A single hero who rallied against the corrupt practices of the church?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is impossible to destroy any faith (major ones that is) in the span of a year. Decades sounds more likely. Avoiding bloodshed is also impossible, as you will have to deal with fanatics who will think you are the incarnation of the devil.

Now that being said, the best way to destroy a religion is to make people *lose faith in it*. Important people are like representatives of that religion, therefore making them look bad will deliver a blow to the religion. Since the important people are corrupt, giving a proof of that would be the best way to destroy a majority of peoples faith in that religion. It doesn't hurt to spice things up a bit either ☺

There are few problems with this, like the fact that the Church will try to cover things up (and try to assassinate you), and the fact that you need to be someone important & trustworthy in order to make people believe you. The best way would be to act as the **representative of the Goddess.** You can cast a few healing spells and other showy magics to make yourself believable, and claim that if the Church is innocent, then why isn't the Goddess appearing for them? If they claim that you are a fake, give some proof by using magic that a normal mage cannot do (the others don't know that other magicians are helping you out in the background, and you can claim that the Goddess is helping you) Claim yourself as the true representative, and give proofs of what cruelties the Church has done. If the Church proclaims to be the saviour of humanity, show them the people who have died of suspicious causes. Keep giving examples in order to instil doubt in peoples minds.

This won't topple the Church in one go, but it will still cause a lot of chaos. If the Church ignores the questions posed by the people, more people will stop believing. If they try to quash rebellion, it will only flame the fire.

(Note: This won't solve the problem easily, and the Church can just shoot you and claim later that you are a enemy or something. But it's impossible to deal with the problem in the constraints that the OP has given)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this although I voted to close, however I'm not going to answer the question as currently phrased. I'm only going to give general advice.

First, I want to underline a few facts that you have stated: the religion is universally adopted, enjoys the support of a billion followers or more, and has its own military order (palladins).

You can't "fight" this sort of insitution. By its very size it is nearly impossible to topple. Its military, economic, political, and propagandistic strength is far more than 7 heroes can combat. The demons even less so.

Religious fervor is not based on fact, it is based on ***faith***, and approaching the situation with logical arguments such as "the demons didn't kill anyone and we have proof" is not going to get you anywhere. Your only chance to defeating such a massive insitution is to completely discredit their current leadership, and prove to the world that ***your*** heroes are the ones who enjoy the Goddess's favor.

In other words you need ***divine intervention***.

How you go about having your nameless heroes become prophets of the Goddess is your business as the story teller, however the general idea is that the Goddess should take an active role in undermining the Church leadership, or at least support the heroes in some critical moment, such that "the people" come to believe that they are her representatives, not the Church leader.

Acceptance of the Demons will not come overnight. Most likely the best thing for them to do would be to stay far away from human lands. But your heroes might be able to take down the corrupt Church leaders, and stop the war of extermination against them. Whether this can happen in a year, however, is debatable.

Comment: Why the downvotes? And why is every answer here getting them? Seems fishy.

Comment: Yeah, not fishy at all.  I acutally up voted you to get you back to zero.  Oh well

Comment: @AndreiROM, there was one that didn't, but I've topped you up again :)

Comment: @AndreiROM : Lol, I also got a downvote XD  It seems that all of us got downvotes XD  Some troll keeps downvoting some of my questions (after I've received like 10 upvotes) and gives a close vote -.-

Answer (score 1):

re·li·gion
rəˈlijən/
noun
the belief in and worship of a superhuman controlling power, especially a personal God or gods.

- a particular system of faith and worship.

Based on this definition and my own personal experience, faith in something larger and more powerful than yourself - a god or goddess - is not totally dependant on the teachers and ministers.  Instead faith relies in a deeply held belief in the god[dess] and true believers will not just change tack because you expose a teacher or minister as a fraud.  The "Faithful" will allow themselves to be imprisoned, tortured, and killed before renouncing their faith.

Destroying the church would entail exposing the god or goddess as a fanciful creation and then to ensure that EVERY single paritioner was located and convinced or silenced.  In a medieval setting this would be very, very hard to do and it would not be quick in the slightest.

In your scenario, you'd be better off to find a faithful follower, known for integrity, questioning church leadership, with leadership traits, and promote them to a ministerial position in the church.  It would be much more expedient to purge the church of corruption than try to destory it.

Comment: Your pronunciation makes no sense. Lower-case /i/ is like in *seen* or *bean*, and /j/ is an English *y*.    IAC how is that relevant?

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to hear more of this releeyun - sounds interesting,

Comment: Perform a Google search gents.  I didn't make it up and Merriam Webster is similar.  Argue with them.

Comment: @JDługosz There is more than one way to transcribe pronunciations, not just IPA. In IPA this would be /rəˈlɪdʒən/. There are many alternatives, the one above may be NOAD.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English